# MVC - Web API - Optional Struct Parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a struct called `PaginationInput` and I want to have it as an optional parameter to a Web API Action.

The method definition is as follows:

```
public Foo[] Get(bool includeInactive = false, PaginationInput pagination = default(PaginationInput))
```

However this produces an error when I don't specify `pagination` when calling the API Action:

```
{
  "message": "The request is invalid.",
  "messageDetail": "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'pagination' of non-nullable type 'SyncSoft.Capital.Web.REST.Models.PaginationInput' for method 'SyncSoft.Capital.Web.REST.Models.Entity.Member[] Get(Int32, Boolean, SyncSoft.Capital.Web.REST.Models.PaginationInput, System.String)' in 'SyncSoft.Capital.Web.REST.Controllers.Entities.MemberController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."
}
```

Is there a way to resolve this without resorting to making the `pagination` parameter nullable? (`PaginationInput? pagination = null`)

EDIT:

Example request:

http://localhost:65265/Foo/123/Bar?includeInactive=true

Fails but will work if I put `pagination` parameter in:

http://localhost:65265/Foo/123/Bar?includeInactive=true&pagination=10rows,page1

Comment: Try to use `[FromUri]` for  `PaginationInput` on get method

Comment: @Div No change.

Comment: Show example of request

Comment: @Nkosi I have added an example for working and non-working requests. Since this just GET, no body is required, only the query string.

Comment: In the interest of keeping provided information relevant to the issue, I omitted the last parameter.

Comment: Don't use PaginationInput pagination = default(PaginationInput). Use PaginationInput pagination = null instead. I think I remember reading somewhere you can't use the default keyword in webapi

Answer (score 0):

I have concluded that this is not possible. Instead, the struct must be made `Nullable<>` and default to `null`.

```
public Foo[] Get(bool includeInactive = false, PaginationInput? pagination = null)
```